# Not able to restore application from powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I accidently deleted an Azure Ad application and want to restore it from Powershell.

To get the Azure Ad deleted application, I found this command `Get-AzureADDeletedApplication`.

To restore the application, I am using the below command:

```
Restore-AzureADDeletedApplication
```

But I am getting Resource not found error.
Please help me with the error and where I am going wrong.

Comment: Does your deleted application show up when running `Get-AzureADDeletedApplication`?

Comment: Yes it shows up

Comment: And, just to confirm, you're passing the `ObjectID` of the application to `Restore-AzureADDeletedApplication` rather than the `ApplicationID` as passing the app id will result in the error you're seeing?

Comment: Please edit to show what parameters you're passing. Currently you haven't provided enough detail. Aside from all parameters, show your exact output too. (note: be sure to obfuscate any parameters that might be a security risk but... you really need to show the full call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You `@NiMux` for your suggestion- We have tested in our environment; it is working fine using the  `objectId`  there is no option to pass  `clientId`  as a parameter of  `Restore-AzureADDeletedApplication`.

If you are passing the  `ClientId`  forcefully it will give you an error.

**Note**:
The `AppRegistration` can be restored but it won't restore the Enterprise Application once deleted.

[image]

**Output**: After restoring the `AppRegistration`.

[image]

Comment: Please don't take someone's comment and turn it into an answer. And the comment is asking a question that hasn't been answered yet. If the OP is passing the wrong thing, then this question should be closed as 'typo or could not be reproduced' - there's no need to post so much content when the OP hasn't even provided the details of the call they are making (as I've commented under the question). Also: once again, please be sure to post formatted code, not images of code ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551))